# LinearLayout just ignores MvxBind (MvvmCross)

Tags: binding, xamarin.android, android-linearlayout, mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind LinearLayout to show/hide in accordance with ViewModel State.
For some reason it works great for buttons and textviews but not for LinearLayout.

What could be the reason?

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25dp"
                android:minHeight="25dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                local:MvxBind="Visibility WaitingForConfirmation">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried a quick test using the `bool Visible` pseudo-property and it worked for both `TextView` and for `LinearLayout`

```
<TextView
    android:text="Random text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Visible Generosity &gt; 12" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="Visible Generosity &gt; 12" />
```

The `Visibility` property binds to the same underlying Android hide/display mechanism - it just uses the Visibility plugin to convert `bool`->`Visibility` enum - so the code should work for that too...

---

**Update**: I also tried within the Droid sample https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ValueConversion

Within this I just changed the displayed view to `LinearLayout` in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ValueConversion/ValueConversion.UI.Droid/Resources/Layout/View_Visibility.axml

This sample worked fine:

[image: visconv]

---

What is `WaitingForConfirmation`? I suspect it's a bool, in which case you will need to use a visibility converter, just as you do in Windows binding. A standard visibility converter is provided in the Visibility plugin, and can be used:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility MakeItVisible, Converter=Visibility" />
```

---

One final note: MvvmCross does continue to adapt (and hopefully improve) its binding type conversion - so at some point you may be able to get away with using `bool`s with `Visibility enums` - but this probably isn't ever going to be recommended practice - normally it's better to use value converters to take control of your binding operations (just like in Windows).

Comment: You abolutely correct, WaitingForConfirmation - is bool.
And I' using converter as well. For some reason this bindin is just ignored. Thank you for sample, I'm glad that it is just an error i nmy code which I'm still looking for. Alex